# Adding/ Removing markers in quickwidget openstreet map

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm using QQuickwidget in my QT5 gui. I've loaded an openstreet map on it by adding qml files accordingly. 
By adding a function in the qml file, I call it through the cpp file by using QMetaObject::invokeMethod. This function adds markers at certain coordinates. This is because I want to control my markers through c++ code itself.

My problem: I am able to load the map and the markers successfully, but I'm not able to remove the markers. My aim is to show the path of a moving object on a map. Therefore, using a timer, I want to update it's position periodically. Every t_samp seconds, I want to remove the marker and add it somewhere else.

the 'item' created in the addMarker code is added to the map by using map.addMapItem(item). By appending map.removeMapItem(item) to the function, the marker disappears. But, the problem is, I can't seem to be able to access 'item' outside the function. Therefore, I cant use map.removeMapItem since I cant input the marker. 
I also tried making the function output 'item', so that I can then use it to add/remove the marker. Unfortunately, I dont know the data type of item, and hence cant receive it.

```
mapview.qml:



import QtQuick 2.12
import QtLocation 5.12
import QtPositioning 5.12

Item {

    id: window
    Plugin
    {
        id: mapPlugin
        name:"osm"

    }

    function addMarker(latitude, longitude)
    {
        var component= Qt.createComponent("qrc:///qml/marker.qml")
        var item= component.createObject(window, {coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(latitude,longitude)})


        map.addMapItem(item)

    }


    Map
    {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(15.4561,73.8021);
        zoomLevel: 14

    }

}
```

```
marker.qml:

import QtQuick 2.12
import QtLocation 5.12
import QtPositioning 5.12

    MapQuickItem
    {
    id: marker
    anchorPoint.x: marker.width / 4
    anchorPoint.y: marker.height

    sourceItem: Image
        {

            id: icon
            source: "qrc:///images/mapmark.png"
            sourceSize.width: 50
            sourceSize.height: 50


        }

    }
```

```
mainwindow.cpp: (only relevant snippet)

QObject* target= qobject_cast<QObject*>(ui->quickWidget->rootObject());
    QString functionName= "addMarker";

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(target,functionName.toUtf8().constData(), Qt::AutoConnection, Q_ARG(QVariant, 15.4561), Q_ARG(QVariant,73.8021));
```

Comment: From what I understand you only want to see a single marker, so you add, remove, add, etc. Am I right?

Comment: In essence, yes. If I can do it with one marker, I can do it with multiple. My plan is to have two different types of markers. One type showing its current position, the second showing it's history. So every t seconds, I would like to displace the first type, and add the second type at that location. This would make a trail of sorts.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand you, you want a marker that shows the current position and other markers that show the previous positions. Am I right?

Comment: That's right...

Comment: Okay, as a last point Do the markers that show the history show the position since the program starts or only the last n positions?

Comment: Since the program starts. Thats the simpler case right? Once we add the 'history' marker, we can just leave them be.

Comment: depending on what you want, the correct solution changes. It is not the same to handle a marker that thousands of markers

Comment: Well okay then. Last N markers should be good, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of exporting the QML marker to C++, it is best to export a QObject from C++ to QML, and since you want to handle several markers you must use a model.

**Explanation of the approach:**

The MVC pattern is Qt's natural way of handling a lot of information, and for this it implements views such as MapItemView, and models that can be created based on QAbstractXXXModel. So only the responsibility is to specialize the classes for the objective, such as implementing the logic of just keeping n elements and if there is a new element, remove the oldest one.

**Why is it better to export a QObject to QML?** The life cycle of the objects in QML are handled by QML, so in your case you could access the markers at a given time QML could delete it so that the pointer in C ++ would append non-reserved memory. Another advantage is that the Q_PROPERTY are recognized in QML and the data type is known by QML and C ++, unlike if you export a QML object to C ++ since only the properties of QObject or QQuickItem will be used. Also when exported using setContextProperty the QObject is global. The disadvantage is that more code is added. For more details read [Interacting with QML from C++](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-bestpractices.html#interacting-with-qml-from-c).

**markermodel.h**

```cpp
#ifndef MARKERMODEL_H
#define MARKERMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QGeoCoordinate>

class MarkerModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QGeoCoordinate current READ current NOTIFY currentChanged)
public:
    enum MarkerRoles{
        PositionRole = Qt::UserRole + 1000,
    };
    explicit MarkerModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void moveMarker(const QGeoCoordinate & coordinate);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
    int maxMarkers() const;
    void setMaxMarkers(int maxMarkers=0);
    QGeoCoordinate current() const;
signals:
    void currentChanged();
private:
    void insert(int row, const QGeoCoordinate & coordinate);
    void removeLastMarker();
    QList<QGeoCoordinate> m_markers;
    QGeoCoordinate m_current;
    int m_maxMarkers;
};

#endif // MARKERMODEL_H
```

**markermodel.cpp**

```cpp
#include "markermodel.h"

MarkerModel::MarkerModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent),
      m_maxMarkers(0)
{
}

void MarkerModel::moveMarker(const QGeoCoordinate &coordinate)
{
    QGeoCoordinate last = m_current;
    m_current = coordinate;
    Q_EMIT currentChanged();
    if(!last.isValid())
        return;
    if(m_maxMarkers == 0){
        insert(0, last);
        return;
    }
    if(rowCount() >= m_maxMarkers){
        while (rowCount() >= m_maxMarkers)
            removeLastMarker();
        removeLastMarker();
    }
    insert(0, last);
}
int MarkerModel::maxMarkers() const
{
    return m_maxMarkers;
}

void MarkerModel::setMaxMarkers(int maxMarkers)
{
    m_maxMarkers = maxMarkers > 1 ? maxMarkers: 0;
}

QGeoCoordinate MarkerModel::current() const
{
    return m_current;
}

int MarkerModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid())
        return 0;
    return m_markers.count();
}

QVariant MarkerModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();
    if(role == PositionRole)
        return QVariant::fromValue(m_markers[index.row()]);
    return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> MarkerModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[PositionRole] = "position";
    return roles;
}

void MarkerModel::insert(int row, const QGeoCoordinate & coordinate)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row, row);
    m_markers.insert(row, coordinate);
    endInsertRows();
}

void MarkerModel::removeLastMarker()
{
    if(m_markers.isEmpty())
        return;
    beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount()-1, rowCount()-1);
    m_markers.removeLast();
    endRemoveRows();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```cpp
// ...
MarkerModel marker_model;
// ...
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
// ...
ui->quickWidget->rootContext()->setContextProperty("marker_model", &marker_model);
ui->quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/mapview.qml"));
// ...
```

**main.qml**

```
// ...
Map{
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: mapPlugin
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(15.4561,73.8021);
    zoomLevel: 14
    Marker{
        coordinate: marker_model.current
    }
    MapItemView{
        model: marker_model
        delegate: Marker{
            coordinate: model.position
        }
    }
}
// ...
```

<sub>The complete example is [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/56425038)</sub>

Comment: On compiling, error: in mapview.qml: Marker is not a type (line 17)..? On a separate note, thanks! This is a comprehensive answer, and I've still got to go through it to understand what you did. Apart from the answer, do you mind explaining why you used this approach? 'Its best to export a QObject from C++ to QML instead'. Why is this so?

Comment: @JeetYadav 1) Have you downloaded my project or have you adapted it to yours? I just compiled it back and I have not had the problem you point out, I recommend downloading my project, compiling and executing it, for example the .qml that will be QML items to be capitalized, in your code marker is not capitalized by what I corregi that is my code Have you made that change you? 2) I will respond with an edit to your questions

Comment: 1)Sorted it out. Its working great!  2) Thanks, looking forward to it.

Comment: @ellyanesc. Just wanted to clarify some things. So in this example, am I correct to say that n-1 markers are handled by mapitemview with the model, and the current marker is handled my the "Marker" object? So the model only holds the n-1 markers?

Comment: @jet Exactly, since the characteristic of the "current marker" is different from others.

Comment: @ellyanesc. Thats brilliant. I've spent a good amount of time poring through documentation, but I'm still a bit fuzzy here: how are these related and used- Qt:userrole, QHash, Qlist and the func  'data'. I'm confused about which number corresponds to which index, and what is actually storing the information. If you could help me understand this or point me somewhere I could learn, I'd be grateful. You've already helped me immensely. Thanks :)

Comment: @jet The first thing to learn is how Qt implements the MVC model: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html, then how it applies to QML: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html

Comment: @ellyanesc. I went through the documentation. One clarification needed: I dont understand how the model is notifying the view that its changing, it isnt explicitly done in this example. In the documentation, they say that QAbstractItemModel's can do this automatically, but they also say that we have to reimplement functions like setData(), begininsertrows() etc and emit dataChanged()?

Comment: @jet In the code I have proposed, the actions I have implemented are the add and remove, and if you look at my code I have used beginInsertRows-endInsertRows and beginRemoveRows-endRemoveRows, respectively. These functions serve to protect the data, for example: when you are deleting a row the view asks for row information Do not you think that would throw an error? In addition, these methods emit the signals rowsAboutToBeInserted-rowsInserted and rowsAboutToBeMoved-rowsRemoved a moment before and after the modification, respectively.

Comment: @jet [cont.] So with those methods the view is notified. The data of an item is not modified so I have not implemented the setData method, that is, the model is not editable but it can delete and remove items. Finally just follow the recommendations, that kind of functionality are transparent to the user

Comment: @ellyanesc. That was really well explained. Again, thanks. :)